# sqlite operation guidance with listview

Tags: android, sqlite

first of all please forgive me for asking very broad question, I am designing an android app which requires atleast 600 rows and about 50 columns in a single table, i have created code for it and initialized my db with data required. 
Now i am faced with a simple problem and no where to go or look for basically i [image: database example]

i have situation matches to attached table, wherein separate list activities are called for each column, for example first list activity should have product name only while clicking in first activity user shifts to new list activity having year after clicking year user goes to version and so on. it is to be noted that filtering is required at each stage to remove unrelated entry.
can any one guide me how to achieve this goal.
thanks and regards

Comment: Man your app is really nice! Looks a lot like a Windows Operating System. ^^ (jk)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite a exquisite behaviour to implement... But hey, if you do wanna do this, here is a possible approach:

Your ListView will need a custom adapter implemented using BaseAdapter. This CustomBaseAdapter will be backed up by a list of lists of objects, a "stack of selections" and a integer state holder.

The list of lists of objects will form a matrix just like your image containing "SN, product, year, version, color, custom text" respective lists, that will be used together with the state holder that allows you to know in what of those lists the mode is currently in and what mode next to go.

Your "stack of selections" will help you do the filtering needed by the user, based on what stack level you are currently in, that will also be controlled by the state holder.

Everytime the user clicks one row, your ListView will fire the onItemClick that calls your adapter to add the user selection to the "stack of selections", and change its state to update the data based on the state holder next possibility. Remember your state holder cannot be bigger then your matrices number of columns, since it holds the column currently being showed.

The "change its state" part of the above is simply changing the currently state holder and calling notifyDataSetChanged, assuming you will implement a getView method on your adapter that takes note of the currently state of the state holder and the current selections of the "stack of selections" to filter the content of the list it will show accordingly.

The ListView will refresh itself and your getView method from your adapter will get the views based on your current state.

Sorry for the big response, i can try to explain better if needed.